# I have some problems,related to title() method in python

Tags: python-3.x

we know that title() method capitalizes the first letter of a string but if my string starts with a digit e.g. `"I     love to watch   3d movies"`. My expected output for this string is `"I     Love To Watch   3d Movies"`.The title method is capitalizing also the letter "d", how can I solve this problem

```
s=input()
p=s.title()
print(p)
```

Comment: you can loop throught the string and check if the first char is not a number. if not then capitalize it and if not then don't. to implement this you have to loop throught s.split() and then make your check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the capitalize function and seems that it does what you want to achieve:

```
s = "i love watching 3d movies"
res = ""
for t in s.split():   # loop through your string
    res += t.capitalize()+ " "   # capitalize the first word 

print(res)    # I Love Watching 3d Movies
```

so if you need the spaces to stay there you have to do it manually. you can check the index or make a counter where exactly you need those spaces and then just add spaces when i=1 or when i=4 for example. But if you just want to change the "D" to "d" this can be easily replaced with the replace method:

```
s = "i    love watching     3d movies"

result = s.title().replace("D", "d")
```

another solution is you can check for the index of the numbers in your string:

```
def get_numbers_index(strng):
    for i in range(len(strng)):
        try:
            int(strng[i])
            return i
        except:
            pass

i = get_numbers_index(s)   # get the index of the number in your str
s1 = s.title()   # Capitalize your str
res = s1.replace(s1[i+1], s[i+1])  # replace the character after the number with the lower value of the first string
print(res)    # I    Love Watching     3d Movies
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but there are some spaces between "I" and "love", also between "watch" and "3d"

Comment: so you don't need spaces ? or what exactly is the expected output ?

Comment: Yeah I need those spaces

Comment: well apparently you have to do it manually. I ll post a solution on to make it manually

Comment: Okay but I can't do it  manually.What if my inputs are random!

Comment: @SunjareeIbnZulfiker you can make a function to return the index of the number in your string and then replace the character next to it

Comment: @SunjareeIbnZulfiker it should now work as you expected.

Comment: @SunjareeIbnZulfiker did that worked for you or did you encounter another problem?

Comment: @SunjareeIbnZulfiker can you please accept the answer so that it will be closed ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it is a feature!

Let me cite [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

> The algorithm uses a simple language-independent definition of a word
>   as groups of consecutive letters. The definition works in many
>   contexts but it means that apostrophes in contractions and possessives
>   form word boundaries, which may not be the desired result

In short - you are welcome to improve the implementation and raise a merge request to the Python standard library code.